Deploy Azure Files share as a network drive to user's corporate machines
We are trying to deploy an Azure Files SMB share to users' corporate machines and have that share mapped in their Windows Explorer. The intent is to emulate a traditional on-prem network "share drive". This is easier for on-prem and Hybrid organizations, but it's a bit more challenging for cloud-only organizations. We are 100% cloud-based in M365 and EntraID. I've been reading all the Microsoft docs I can find and trying to cobble together a plan. I cannot find an all-in-one resource for this use case. I'm still fuzzy on some details that I'm sure are implied in the docs, but I am missing. Here goes.

We are M365/EntraID based, with a P2 tenant.
We have an Azure tenant connected to our M365/EntraID tenant.
Resource Group created, call it corporate-storage-RG
Storage account created, call it corporate-storage-SA
Azure File Share created, call it test-file-share
Entra Domain Services created using the same domain as our company, call it my-corp.com. This is our main domain. Creating the Entra Domain Services creates all the necessary Virtual Networks, public IP, security group, etc.
Azure File Share Identity Based Access configured as Microsoft Entra Domain Services
VM created in corporate-storage-RG, call it corporate-storage-VM.

I'm having trouble joining the VM to the my-corp.com domain services created above. I'm getting an error when using my creds. Here's my first question, should I use a different domain name than our main domain? Microsoft examples use aadcontoso vs contoso. I didn't see any direction to use a different name, so I'm asking. If I should use a different domain name, do I have to add that domain in M365 and a corresponding DNS record on our site?
My understanding is that once I get the VM joined to the Azure domain, the VM will connect to the Azure File Share, and the users will access the shares through the VM. Do I have to add the EntraID groups to the Azure domain?
Are there any other gotchas I may be missing?
